Sqlite datetime saves one day less than the original input
TypeORM entity:
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'nvarchar',
    length: 50,
    nullable: false,
    unique: true
  })
  email: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'nvarchar',
    length: 30,
    nullable: false,
  })
  password: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'nvarchar',
    length: 50,
    nullable: false
  })
  fullName: string

  @Column({
    type: 'datetime',
    nullable: false
  })
  dateOfBirth: Date
}


DTO:
import { IsDate, IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  fullName: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  dateOfBirth: string;
}

Service:
  async createUserAsync(user: CreateUserDto) {

    const users = await this.dataService.users.findOneBy({
      email: user.email,
    });
    if (users) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Email in use email:${user.email}`);
    }

    const salt = randomBytes(8).toString('hex');
    const hash = (await this._scrypt(user.password, salt, 32)) as Buffer;

    const result = salt + '.' + hash.toString('hex');

    user.password = result;

    user.dateOfBirth = new Date(user.dateOfBirth).toISOString();
    const createdUser = await this.dataService.users.create(user);
    const savedUser = await this.dataService.users.save(createdUser);

    return savedUser;
  }


payload:
{
fullName:'xxx',
email:'a@a.com',
password: '1234',
dateFfBith: '9/4/2024'
}
saved data:
{
fullName:'xxx',
email:'a@a.com',
password: '1234',
dateOfBith: '9/3/2024' // one day less
}
Payload contains the original date that the client provided, however, when it saves in the sqlite db, it saves one day less than the original provided date.

To save date properly in sqlite, you need to send the data without timezone info.
    const formSubmitAction = (values: any) => {
        form.resetFields();
        if(isExpense){
            values.expenseDate =  moment(values.date.toISOString()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }else{
            values.depositDate = moment(values.date.toISOString()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }
        delete values['date'];
        submitFormAction(values);
    }


Here I'm using momentjs to remove the timezone info from the date.
